# $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{-1}{T}\frac{1}{2(\cosh(\omega/T)+1)}\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1+(\omega/\Delta)^{2}}}{1+(\omega/\Delta)^{2}}}d\omega$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I want to solve the integral

\begin{align}
 X = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f'_{T}(\omega)\tau_\Delta(\omega)d\omega
\end{align}

with $f'_T(\omega)=\frac{-1}{T}\frac{1}{2(\cosh(\omega/T)+1)}$ the derivative of the Fermi function, $\tau_\Delta(\omega)=\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1+(\omega/\Delta)^{2}}}{1+(\omega/\Delta)^{2}}}$ and $T,\Delta\in\Bbb{R}_{\ge0}$.

The integral is related to the study of the conductance of a quantum impurity at low temperatures.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The integral is
$$
X=2\sqrt{\frac{2\pi\Delta}T}~\Re\left(e^{i\pi/4}\text{Li}_{-1/2}(-e^{i\Delta/T})\right)
$$
where $\text{Li}_s(z)$ is the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

It seems that it is originally a physics problem (perhaps related to signal processing) and I would appreciate it if OP could share some background.

---

It is worth noticing that the so-called *Forta function* satisfies (the verification is left as an exercise)
$$
\tau_\Delta(\omega)=\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1+(\omega/\Delta)^{2}}}{1+(\omega/\Delta)^{2}}}=\sqrt2~\Re\frac1{\sqrt{1+i\omega/\Delta}}
$$
Here the branch cut of square root is the conventional negative real axis.

For the sake of simplicity, let $x=\dfrac{\omega}{2T},a=\dfrac{\Delta}{2T}$, so

$$
X=-\frac{1}{T}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2(\cosh(\omega/T)+1)}\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1+(\omega/\Delta)^{2}}}{1+(\omega/\Delta)^{2}}}d\omega
=-\frac1{\sqrt2}\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\text{sech}^2x}{\sqrt{1+ix/a}}dx}_{I}
$$
It suffices to evaluate $I$.

Let $z=1+ix/a$ and view the integral as one on the vertical line $\Re(z)=1$ on the complex plain. Since the integrand is analytic in the rectangle $(-i\infty,1+i\infty)$, we can safely deform the contour to the imaginary axis $\Re(z)=0$ with simple verification that the integral on the horizontal lines vanish. Hence,
$$
I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\text{sech}^2(x+ia)}{\sqrt{ix/a}}dx=e^{-i\pi/4}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\text{sech}^2(x+ia)}{\sqrt{x/a}}dx+e^{i\pi/4}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\text{sech}^2(x-ia)}{\sqrt{x/a}}dx
$$
The rest is all about evaluating the Mellin transform.
$$
\begin{align}
&M=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}}{\cosh^2(x+b)}dx
\\=& -4 \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}\left(\sum _{n\ge1}(-1)^n n e^{-2 n (x+b)}\right)dx
\\=&-4\sum _{n\ge1}(-1)^n ne^{-2nb}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}e^{-2nx}dx
\\=&-2^{2-s}\Gamma(s)\sum _{n\ge1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{s-1}}e^{-2nb}
\\=&-2^{2-s}\Gamma(s)\text{Li}_{s-1}(-e^{-2b})
\end{align}
$$
The identity holds as long as the integral converges via analytic continuation of the polylogarithm.

The OP's integral is therefore
$$
X=-\sqrt{2a}~\Re\left(e^{i\pi/4}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\text{sech}^2(x-ia)}{\sqrt{x}}dx\right)
=4\sqrt{\pi a}~\Re\left(e^{i\pi/4}\text{Li}_{-1/2}(-e^{2ia})\right)
$$
plugging in the original parameters yields the final result.

It can be further simplified formally using, for example, the [inverse tangent integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_tangent_integral). Nevertheless, to my perspective none are essential since few identities are known to $\text{Li}_{-1/2}$ or related functions.

A more precise statement of this method can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4656967), under @Sangchul Lee's answer.

Comment: Thank you for your kind words and detailed explanation.

Answer (score 7):

We can also show that $$X= -\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\Delta}{\pi T}} \ \zeta \left(\frac{3}{2}, \frac{\Delta }{2 \pi T} + \frac{1}{2} \right), $$ where $\zeta(s,a)$ is the [Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function), defined for $\Re(s) >1$ by the series $$\zeta(s,a)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+a)^{s}}. $$

(EDIT: As **Po1ynomial** pointed out in the comments, our results our related by [Hurwitz's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function#Hurwitz%27s_formula).)

We'll need the [integral formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/977093/16033) $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}\cos(ux)}{\sqrt{x}} \, \mathrm dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1+u ^{2}}}{1+ u^{2}}},   \quad u \in \mathbb{R},  $$

and the integral formula $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(bx)}{\cosh^{2}(x)} \, \mathrm dx =  \pi b \operatorname{csch} \left(\frac{\pi b}{2} \right), \quad b \in \mathbb{R},$$ the latter of which can be derived using a rectangular contour of fixed height or otherwise.

Then we have

$$ \begin{align} X &= -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{T} \frac{1}{2 \left(\cosh \left(\omega/T \right)+1 \right)} \, \sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1+\left(\omega/\Delta \right)^{2}}}{1+ \left(\omega/\Delta \right)^{2}}} \, \mathrm d \omega \\  &= -\frac{\Delta}{2T} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\cosh \left(\frac{\Delta u}{T}\right)+1 } \, \sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1+u ^{2}}}{1+ u^{2}}} \, \mathrm du  \\ &=  -\frac{\Delta}{4T} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\cosh^{2} \left(\frac{\Delta u}{2T}\right)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x} \cos(ux)}{\sqrt{x}} \, \mathrm dx \,  \mathrm du  \\ &= -\frac{\Delta}{4T} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(xu)}{\cosh^{2} \left(\frac{\Delta u}{2T}\right)} \, \mathrm du \,  \mathrm dx \\ &= -\frac{\Delta}{4T} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(xu)}{\cosh^{2} (\alpha u )} \, \mathrm du \,  \mathrm dx \\ &= -\frac{\Delta}{4T} \frac{1}{\alpha} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos\left( \frac{xv}{\alpha}\right)}{\cosh^{2} (v )} \, \mathrm dv \,  \mathrm dx \\ &= -\frac{\Delta}{4T} \frac{1}{\alpha} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}   \frac{\pi x}{\alpha} \,  \operatorname{csch} \left(\frac{\pi x}{2 \alpha} \right) \,  \mathrm dx  \\ &=  -\frac{\Delta}{2T} \frac{\pi}{\alpha^{2}} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\int_{0}^{\infty} \sqrt{x} \, e^{-x}   \,  \frac{e^{- \pi x/(2 \alpha)}}{1-e^{-\pi x/\alpha}} \,  \mathrm dx \\ &= -\frac{\Delta}{2T} \frac{\pi}{\alpha^{2}} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\int_{0}^{\infty} \sqrt{x} \, e^{-x}   \,  e^{- \pi x/(2 \alpha)} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{- \pi n x/\alpha}\,  \mathrm dx \\ &= -\frac{\Delta}{2T} \frac{\pi}{\alpha^{2}} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} \sqrt{x} \, e^{-x\left(1+ \pi/(2 \alpha)+\pi n /\alpha \right)}\,  \mathrm dx \\ &\overset{(1)}{=}  -\frac{\Delta}{2T} \frac{\pi}{\alpha^{2}} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \frac{1}{\left(1+ \frac{\pi}{2 \alpha} + \frac{\pi n}{\alpha} \right)^{3/2}} \\ &=  -\frac{\Delta}{4T} \frac{\pi^{3/2} }{\alpha^{2}} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\frac{\alpha}{\pi} \right)^{3/2}}{\left(n+ \frac{\alpha}{\pi} + \frac{1}{2} \right)^{3/2}} \\ &= -\frac{\Delta}{4T} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha}} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \, \zeta \left(\frac{3}{2}, \frac{\alpha}{\pi} + \frac{1}{2} \right) \\ &= -\frac{\Delta}{4T} \sqrt{\frac{2T}{\Delta}} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \, \zeta \left(\frac{3}{2}, \frac{\Delta }{2 \pi T} + \frac{1}{2} \right) \\ &= -\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\Delta}{\pi T}} \, \zeta \left(\frac{3}{2}, \frac{\Delta }{2 \pi T} + \frac{1}{2} \right). \end{align}$$

---

$(1)$ $\int_{0}^{\infty} \sqrt{x} e^{-ax} \, \mathrm dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} a^{-3/2}, \quad a >0 $

Comment: (+1) Nice solution avoiding contour integration. I think the result is connected to mine via $\displaystyle i^{-s} \mathrm{Li}_{s}\left(e^{2 \pi i x}\right)+i^{s} \operatorname{Li}_{s}\left(e^{-2 \pi i x}\right)=\frac{(2 \pi)^{s}}{\Gamma(s)} \zeta(1-s, x)$. This simplification had slipped out of my mind, so thank you for reminding me that.

Comment: @Po1ynomial   Thanks.  I had forgotten about Hurwitz's formula.  I found a proof using contour integration in my old notes.